# If $a$ is relatively prime to $m$ and $a \equiv b\ (\textrm{mod}\ m)$, is $b$ relatively prime to $m$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> If $a$ is relatively prime to $m$ and $a \equiv b\ (\textrm{mod}\ m)$, is $b$ relatively prime to $m$?
>
> **Hint:**. Recall that $a \equiv b\ (\textrm{mod}\ m)$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ differ by a multiple of $m$.

So we have that $\gcd(a, m)=1$ and we would like to see if $\gcd(b,m) = 1.$  So since $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime doesn’t that imply that $m$ is a prime? If so, then the only way that $\gcd(b, m) = 1$ would hold is if $b$ is a prime(?). From the hint we have that $b=a-k\cdot m$, and since we’re multiplying $m$ by some constant $k$ the only way that $b$ would be a prime is that if $a$ is some number that results in $b$ being prime when subtracted from $k \cdot m$(?). By the same logic that $m$ would be prime since $\gcd(a,m)=1$ we would also have that $a$ is a prime. Now do we have some theorem that would state that subtracting some prime $p$ from some number that’s not a prime would result in a prime or am I going totally in a wrong direction here? All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes.  Use the fact that $(a-b)=km$ to deduce that $\gcd(b,m)$ must divide $a$.

Comment: We should not be discussing prime numbers at all here. It is true that if $b$ is prime, then $b,m$ are relatively prime, but this is not the *only* situation in which $b,m$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Note that the fact that this statement is correct is what allows us to compute greatest common divisors via the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: " So since a and m are relatively prime doesn’t that imply that m is a prime?" Why should that be true?  $a$ and $m$ have no factors in common.  But neither of them need to be prime.  $36$ and $1225$ are relatively prime but neither are prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Note that if $d$ is a common divisor of $b,m$ and $a = b + mk$ (for some integer $k$), then $d$ must also be a divisor of $a = b - mk$.

Comment: There’s something I’m not seeing here. Why are we concerned with some common divisor of $b, m$?

Comment: @Daniel The question was, "is $b$ relatively prime to $m$"? And the answer is yes: if  $b$ and $m$ are not relatively prime, then they have a common divisor $d$ not equal to $1$. It follows that $d$ would also be a common divisor of $a$ and $m$, which contradicts our premise that $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @Daniel Actually, here's a quick question: do you understand what the term "relatively prime" (as opposed to just "prime") means?

Comment: Ah this seems to clear it a bit. So can I make the assumption that $\gcd(b, m) = d$ and from here this would imply that since $d$ divides $b$ we would have that $d$ divides $b = a - km$ and for $d$ to divide $a- km$ it would have to divide $a$ which contradicts the initial condition? And $d \neq 1.$

Comment: @Daniel Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you know what relatively prime means.

$a$ and $b$ are relatively prime if they have no factors (other than $1$) in common.  That would mean their greatest common factor, the $\gcd(a,b)$, is equal to $1$.

An example would be $36$ and $1225$.  The factors of $36$ are $1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18$ and $36$.  And the factors of $1225$ are $1, 5, 7, 25,35,49,175,245,1225$ and the only factor they have in common is $1$ so $\gcd(36,1225) = 1$.

So if $a \equiv b \pmod m$ then $m$ divides $a-b$.  If $b$ and $m$ as any factor, $d$, in common then $d|m$ and $m|a-b$ so $d|a-b$.  But $d|b$ so $d|(a-b)+b$ and $d|a$.  So $d$ is a common factor of $a$ and $m$.

But the only common factor $a$ and $m$ have in common is $1$ so $d$ must be $1$ and the only common factor $b$ and $m$ can have in common is $1$.

So $b$ and $m$ must be relatively prime.